# Show that $\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}p^m q^{n-m}$ is maximized at $p = m/n$.

Tags: probability, derivatives, optimization

> (Feller volume 1 p 184) (3.11) $a_0 = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}p^m q^{n-m} \sim \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi npq}}$. A straightforward differentiation shows that the middle term in (3.11) assumes its maximum when $p = m /n$.

Differentiating $\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}p^m q^{n-m}$ with respect to $p$, I have that $-\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}m(n-m)p^{m-1} q^{n-m-1} = 0$. But, I am not sure how to proceed from here. I would appreciate if you give some help.

Comment: Note that $$
\frac{d}{{dp}}p^m q^{n - m}  = q^{n - m - 1} p^{m - 1} (m - np).
$$

Comment: You seem to have tried $(fg)^\prime=f^\prime g^\prime$ rather than $(fg)^\prime=f^\prime g+fg^\prime$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For differentiation w.r.t. $p$, note that $q=1-p$ and $\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$ is constant. So $${d\over dp}p^m q^{n-m}=mp^{m-1}q^{n-m}-(n-m)p^mq^{n-m-1}=0$$which gives you the expected result when $p\ne 0$ or $q\ne 0$.

Comment: Possibly better if I've used "expected result". Corrected. Thanks.